# Permission issue related to managed fields

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-rest-api

I need to use REST API to insert a record into a table called:

conference360__Event__c

This table has the follow four fields:

```
conference360__Event_Start_Date__c
conference360__Event_Start_Time__c
conference360__Event_End_Date__c
conference360__Event_End_Time__c
```

and I need put values in these fields when inserting a record into the table.

The problem is that when inserting a record into this table, I always get the following error message for any of these four fields:

> We can't save this record because the “Event & Case Creation from Room Booking” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details.
> This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: conference360.Event_Trigger: execution of AfterInsert\n\ncaused by:
> System.QueryException: Insufficient permissions: secure query included inaccessible field\n\n(conference360). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.
> Error ID: 2052924026-11322 (-1519010228)k up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 2052924026-11322 (-1519010228)",
> "errorCode":"CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER","fields":[]

How to solve this type of problem? I went to the setup and it seems that these fields are managed and I can't do anything that can fix the problem. Is there a place to configure these fields so that the REST API code can insert values into them?

I am new to Salesforce.